# Solving a triple integral over an ellipse region

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm wondering how I can solve the question below without using the change of the variables (I'm not there yet).

$${\int_0^4}{\int_{-2\sqrt{16-y^2}}^{2\sqrt{16-y^2}}} \int_0^{{16-x^2}/{4-y^2}} dz\,dx\,dy$$

I got this

$${\int_0^4}8/3\sqrt{16-y^2}(8+y^2)dy$$

but it's quite time consuming to solve it without computer or integral table by using trigonometric subs for  something like ${\int}y^2\sqrt{16-y^2}dy$. Could I do a trick to short cut this mess?

I couldn't see an algebra trick perhaps you may. I'm asking this because I can't use the integral table or computer on an exam. The ellipse makes things harder for polar coordinate conversions.

Thank you!

Comment: I suppose that you made a small mistake since your last integral seems to be instead $\int_0^4 \frac{8}{3} \left(16-y^2\right)^{3/2}\,dy$

Comment: And a simple change of variable (think about the simplest trigonometric functions) will give a nice expression to work with.